# Add a component below header in Extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-grid

I have a grid in ExtJs5 with 3 columns. I want to add a component like textfield below header and before starting rows in a grid. Actually i want to filter data based on values in textfield.

Note - I don't want to add a textfield in header. I want below header of a grid.

Here is grid coding -

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
            var studentStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                fields: ['Name', 'Age', 'Fee'],
                data: {
                    items: [
                        { "Name": 'Puneet', "Age": '25', "Fee": '1000' },
                        { "Name": 'Ankit', "Age": '23', "Fee": '2000' },
                        { "Name": 'Rahul', "Age": '24', "Fee": '3000' }
                    ]
                },
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty: 'items'
                    }
                }
            });

            var window = new Ext.Window({
                id: 'grdWindow',
                width: 400,
                title: 'Grid Samples',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                id: 'grdSample',
                                height: 300,
                                store: studentStore,
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        header: 'Name',
                                        dataIndex: 'Name'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        header: 'Age',
                                        dataIndex: 'Age'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        header: 'Fee',
                                        dataIndex: 'Fee'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
                }).show();
            });
```

Here it is image  - result of above code -

I have marked where i need a textboxes -

[image]

I got some solution of this problem like use tbar, bbar, dockedItems and many other but couldn't work as i want.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still interested in solution.

Use `dockedItems` that has `weight` more then the `header` to get the desired result. The `weight` of `header` is 100 so setting the `weight` of `dockedItem` to 101 ensures that the container with your textfield is below it.

```
dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                weight: 101,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width: 100,
                    emptyText: 'textfield 1'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width: 100,
                    emptyText: 'textfield 2'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width: 100,
                    emptyText: 'textfield 3'
                }]
            }]
```

[This is how it will look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtZWk.png)

Fiddle Link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25o2

Answer (score 0):

try changing layout to 'vbox'
and adding another item

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var studentStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: ['Name', 'Age', 'Fee'],
        data: {
            items: [{
                "Name": 'Puneet',
                "Age": '25',
                "Fee": '1000'
            }, {
                "Name": 'Ankit',
                "Age": '23',
                "Fee": '2000'
            }, {
                "Name": 'Rahul',
                "Age": '24',
                "Fee": '3000'
            }]
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    var window = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'grdWindow',
        width: 400,
        title: 'Grid Samples',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                height: 45,
                text: 'Your text is here'
            }, {
                flex: 1,
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'grdSample',
                //height: 300,
                store: studentStore,
                columns: [{
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name'
                }, {
                    header: 'Age',
                    dataIndex: 'Age'
                }, {
                    header: 'Fee',
                    dataIndex: 'Fee'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

Link to fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rba

Comment: Hi Vitaluha, Thanks for reply. When i change layout fit to vbox it doesn't show grid. When i use fit layout and extra item before grid, then it show text box before grid or can say first text box show then grid. But i want to add textboxes below header. Check image in my question and execute your code in fiddler to check it result.

Comment: check this fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rba
Let me know if you need help adding those checkboxes (in item where I have 'label')

Comment: Dear vitaluha, I need textboxes below/after header instead of before header. Please check image again that i have attached in question.

Comment: I got the solution of this question by using below code in grid. But it works only in ExtJs3 and i want in ExtJS5.       
 
         view: new Ext.grid.GridView({
                headerRows: [
                    {
                        columns: [     component..............] 
       }
});